# How can I vote to lock a question?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, locked-posts

If a question has been resolved in the comments (no answer, not a mere typo), how can I vote to get the question locked? The question is meaningful and could be helpful to others. I am not suggesting that it should be deleted.

For example: [Running selenium standalone server gives error: in cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675370/running-selenium-standalone-server-gives-error-in-cmd)

Comment: @lit This is a very weird behavior from a 2k+ user. You should know that we don't *lock* question when an answer is provided (even more when it is a comment instead of an answer). We allow several answers, and the vote system will push at the top the best ones. That how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @Mistalis - I know that SO seeks to suppress extraneous discussion that tends to reduce quality. Sorry I mentioned it. I will accept the answer from Servy as soon as I can. In 6 minutes. Would anyone consider un-downvoting this?

Comment: @lit How is that discussion extraneous?  It's all on topic, it's all constructive, it's not lengthy, and I don't see any other problems with it.  Removing discussions that end up off topic, or that cease being constructive, is appropriate; that doesn't mean *all* discussions need to be removed, let alone the far more severe action of locking the post to prevent not only comments, but upvotes, downvotes, close/reopen votes, editing, etc.

Comment: @Servy - Yes, you are right. It is all on topic and constructive. It appears to resolve the issue. My apologies.

Comment: @lit - "un-down-voting"? You've posted essentially "how to prevent answers on useful on-topic question"  as "feature-request" - so post will appropriately collect downvotes as this clearly against SO goals. You may [edit] the post to clarify what you wanted to ask (but it may be hard as Servy's answer actually address that way of reading the question).

Comment: My apologies for existing here. I am fully thrashed. I accepted Servy's answer. I am done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't.  Only moderators can lock a question.

If you know the answer to an [on topic and appropriate] question and it has not yet been answered, then simply post an answer to the question, so that future readers of the question will have an answer that they can see.

Locking isn't there for questions that have been answered (in comments or otherwise).  It's to prevent actions from being taken on a post when there is some form of conflict among community users (either users continually editing a post to change each other's edits, users reopening/closing or deleting/undeleting a question, repeated off topic comments, even after moderators deleting the off topic comments, etc.) to give users a time to resolve the issue in a more appropriate venue and determine the correct course of action through discussion (possibly in meta or chat), rather than constantly changing the post.  That's not what's going on here.

If you happen to come across a question where one of the previously mentioned issues *is* happening, and the post needs to be locked to prevent all community user interactions with it, then all you can do is flag the post and explain to the moderator why the post needs to be locked, and they can lock it if they feel it is merited.  But again, there isn't any reason to lock this post here.

Answer (score 1):

As @Servy indicated, you can't directly vote to lock, and that's not an appropriate reason to lock.

If it was resolved in the comments, one of the commenters should write an answer. If it was your comment that resolved it, just create an answer. If someone else's comment resolved it, suggest that they add it as an answer; if they don't do so after a reasonable length of time, add it as a community wiki answer (obviously, citing the original author). (I do recognize that that point might be more controversial, though).

If the resolution was a collective effort, it's also appropriate to add a Community Wiki answer summarizing the resolution.